# HTTP POST is not working with Webclient but working with RestTemplate

Tags: http-post, spring-webclient, spring-resttemplate

I am getting Error while making POST calls with webclient as below

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; nested exception is java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

But same request working fine with restetemplate, both code as below

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String baseUrl = "https://somehost/rest/v1/leads.json";
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI(baseUrl);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer 39131a98-7a53-497f-8e04-ca08c35a7775:sj");    
        HttpEntity<Lead> request = new HttpEntity<>(convertToLead(consent), headers);
        ResponseEntity<LeadResponse> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, LeadResponse.class);
        System.out.println(result.getBody().toString());
```

Failed with Webclient code

```
ResponseEntity<Response> leadResponse = marketoWebClient.post().uri("/leads.json").bodyValue(lead).exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(LeadResponse.class).doOnSuccess(response -> {
                    if (clientResponse.statusCode().isError()) {
                        logger.debug("Error Details = {} {}", clientResponse.statusCode(), response);
                    }
                })).block();
```

Comment: I don't see you are passing "Authorization" header. Also better use `.retrieve()` instead of `exchange()` that already has error handling. You could use `onStatus` if you need more granular access to response

Comment: I have built webclient using timeout and Authorization field seperatly, before use